# Does Melatonin help support sleep?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine

<sub>This question brought to you courtesy of a trip to a local supermarket.</sub>

Browsing vitamins/supplements shelf, saw a bottle of [Melatonin](http://www.target.com/p/nature-made-melatonin-3-mg-tablets-120-count/-/A-14701494), on the bottle it said "**Helps support sleep**"

Is this something proven by studies?

Comment: @DanGetz - Damn, didn't show up on "possible duplicates" suggestion list. Good catch!

Comment: Yes. Yes it does.